# compiler error: array required, but String found

Tags: java

Getting a error: array required, but String found.
I checked and rechecked, yet couldn't find anything wrong with my code. What's going wrong? 
I have been introduced to java a year ago, but only when i started working on a project to develop a library management system do I realise the serious deficiencies in my knowledge.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class library{
book[] bk = new book[5];

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    library mainObj = new library();

    mainObj.addBooks();
}

public void addBooks(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Book Name: ");
    String bk = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Author Name: ");
    String aun = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Id: ");
    String i = input.nextLine();

    bk[book.getTotalBookCount()] = new book(bk, aun, i);
}

}

class book{
String name;
String authorName;
String id;
static int totalBookCount = 0;

book(String bkn, String aun, String i){
    name = bkn;
    authorName = aun;
    id = i;
    totalBookCount++;

    System.out.println("Book Added!! ");
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] (pay attention to "minimal"), at very least point to location of the error.

Comment: library.java:39: error: array required, but String found
  bk[book.getTotalBookCount()] = new book(bk, aun, i);
    ^
1 error

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov alrighty.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - strive for sample without vertical scroll and try to avoid unnecessary inputs that may in some cases impact result (i.e. you could replace all input statements with constants like `String bk="book name";`). Note that using good long names let you avoid such problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov will definitely do so next time! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String bk = input.nextLine();

You're shadowing `book[] bk` with that variable. Either change the name of one of them, or use this instead.

> this.bk[book.getTotalBookCount()] = new book(bk, aun, i);

Answer (score 1):

You are using `bk` variable twice. Once at top while declaring array `book[] bk = new book[5];` and once in **addBooks function** `String bk = input.nextLine();` at third line.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `bk` twice for two different types i.e. one for book array and another for string. And in these type of collisions, local type gets priority so,

```
 bk[.....] = ......;
 ^^^^^   
Here, `bk` will be considered as string, but we are using `[]` brackets with it, hence the error: array required, string found.
```